# How to add a folder to the Windows PATH temporarily with Python?

Tags: python, path

How can I add multiple folders to the windows PATH in Python on Windows?

I have multiple programs (wget for windows, phantomjs, casperjs, ...) that I want to use from a python script. And I think it is a good idea to add these folders to the PATH and remove them when the script is ended but I don't know if it's possible...

Comment: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('C:/my/path'))`

Comment: or, `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('C:/my/path'))` if you want your path to have priority.

Comment: @Torxed I think the OP is asking about `%PATH%` rather than the Python module search path.

Comment: @lvc yepp figured that out right after posting, also wanted to be quick about giving `os.environ` as an answer but someone beat me to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%PATH%` is an environment variable, which is visible in Python by doing this:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

this is a string, which you can make arbitrary modifications to. So, you might do this:

```
 os.environ['PATH'] += ';C:\\wget'
```

Any modifications you make will only be visible in your script, and any other processes that you launch from it - you don't need to remove the modifications after you're done just to stop them persisting in the wider OS.

Answer (score -2):

```
import sys

if "C:\\My_Python_Lib" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("C:\\My_Python_Lib")
```

Comment: I think what OP asks for is modifying the PATH env. variable. Your answer updates the path in which python modules are searched for.